# Join table with max condition on one field

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have three table Company, CompanyBenefitPeriods and CompanyContractType. Company and CompanyBenefitPeriods have a one-to-one relationship, and CompanyBenefitPeriods and CompanyContractType have a one-to-many relationship. I want to get a list of companies, each of company with latest CompanyContractType createdOn.

My query looks like this

```
SELECT c FROM Company c 
LEFT JOIN c.companyBenefitPeriods cbp ON  cbp.company.companyNo = c.companyNo 
LEFT JOIN cbp.companyContractType cct ON cct.companyBenefitPeriod.companyBenefitPeriodNo = cbp.companyBenefitPeriodNo 
AND cct.createdOn in (select max(cct.createdOn) from cct)
```

The error 'a column may not be outer-joined to a subquery' show up.
How can I modify the above query to get the desired result.
Thanks for your time.

Edit: The sample data look like this:

```
|---------------------|
|      CompanyNo      |
|---------------------|
|          1          |
|---------------------|

|---------------------|------------------|
|   CompanyBenefitNo  |     CompanyNo    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          1       |
|          2          |          2       |
|                     |                  |

|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|   CompanyContractNo | CompanyBenefitNo |    CompanyNo     |    CreatedOn     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          1       |          1       |   '27-10-2019'   |
|          2          |          1       |          1       |   '27-11-2019'   |
|          3          |          2       |          2       |   '27-12-2019'   |
|          4          |          2       |          2       |   '27-01-2020'   |

The desire result: 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      CompanyNo      | CompanyBenefitNo | CompanyContractNo|    CreatedOn     |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|------------------|
|          1          |          1       |          2       |   '27-11-2019'   |
|          2          |          2       |          4       |   '27-01-2020'   |
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Your question is quite hard to follow.  You are using some three-part naming that is not standard SQL.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the question is tagged _jpa_. Are you aware of [JPQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_Query_Language) ? Perhaps the OP made a mistake when [s]he added the _sql_ tag, or perhaps [s]he did not realize that the _sql_ tag may be misleading?

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your helps. I'm using Spring Data JPA Query. Maybe adding sql tag make you confused. I will give sample data and desired results so you can understand more clearly

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added the sample data and desired results. Hope this can help you to understand more clearly

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions.  It is a bit hard to follow your query.  I think you want:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM Company c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT cpb.*, . . .
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PATITION BY c.companyNo ORDER BY cct.createdOn) as seqnum
      FROM companyBenefitPeriods cbp JOIN
           ccompanyContractType cct 
           ON cct.companyBenefitPeriodNo = cbp.companyBenefitPeriodNo
     ) cpb
     ON cbp.companyNo = c.companyNo AND seqnum = 1;
```